# Syntax error in groovy script - what is wrong?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to execute the following groovy script snippet in my elasticsearch dsl scripting:

`[doc['availabilities.start'], doc['availabilities.end']].transpose().any { (start, end) -> end.date.getMillis() >= 11 } return 2;`
```

and this throws the following error
[image]

I am pretty new in Groovy and unable to figure out what is the wrong syntax here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy doesn't use parentheses around closure parameters, so that should be

```
.any { start, end -> end.date.getMillis() >= 11 }
```

And `return 2;` at the end discards the result of the previous expression, I'm not sure if that was your intention.

Comment: Thank you sooo much @roman . Your solution indeed work, and then after that I went ahead and created a snippet at https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5084327121518592 , but that could not give me the result I was looking for. I wanted to get the name of the wine, bu tit simply print `true` . You can click `edit in console` there to change it

Comment: @JVK Well, that should be another question. `any` returns `boolean`, you need other methods: `[wine,price,taste].transpose().find { w, p, t -> p == 9 }[0]`

Comment: Yes you are right, that should be another question. I accept your answer and appreciate your help,